# perl call subroutine to generate random strings not working

Tags: perl, variables, global-variables, subroutine

The script to generate random strings:

```
sub rand_Strings {
   my @chars = ("A".."Z", "a".."z", "0".."9");
   my $string;
   $string .= $chars[rand @chars] for 1..8;
}

my $strings = &rand_Strings;
print $strings;
```

However, it works when it is not in a subroutine. And also works if the $string is a global variable. What did I miss? Thanks,

Comment: Add `return $string` inside your subroutine.  Also, you do not need the `&` infront of the subroutine name, that is the (very) old way of calling a subroutine.  `my $strings = rand_Strings();` will do...the parens are optional.

Comment: Since Perl 5 was released in 1994, it has been unnecessary to use `&` when calling subroutines.

Comment: *"it has been unnecessary to use `&` when calling subroutines"* Not only that, but it is *incorrect*, and `&rand_Strings` should be `rand_Strings()`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to explicitly add a `return` statement inside your subroutine.
The automatic return of the last statement inside a subroutine does not work inside a loop construction, which in your example is a `for` loop.
The postfix version of the `for` loop is equivalent to the regular version with curly braces.

From [perldoc perlsub](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html):

> If no "return" is found and if the last statement is an expression, its
>       value is returned. If the last statement is a loop control structure like
>       a "foreach" or a "while", the returned value is unspecified. The empty sub
>       returns the empty list.

Comment: Dear @xxfelixxx, I found that the posted problem is not my real problem, however, your answer does solve the posted problem and I managed to work out on my real problem. Thank you all the same!

Comment: Glad it worked out for you.  You can try running `perlcritic` on your code, and it will let you know about non-best practice perl code.